# Why isn't bin/www command not working in my cloud9 (c9) new run configuration?

Tags: node.js, express, mean-stack, cloud9-ide

I'm following along with a Lynda course on MEAN Stack development and while they are running bin/www command in a "New Run Configuration" and its yielding "debugger listening on port 15454"

whereas for me, when I enter `bin/www`, I get the following error:

```
debugger listening on port 15454

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/www'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.runMain [as _onTimeout] (module.js:497:10)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

Comment: It looks like either you missed a step where they told you to the command to download dependencies (the required modules--`www` in this case), or you're in the wrong folder when you execute the command.

Comment: How would I download the required dependencies? I selected the correct folder and still not working.

Comment: In order to help you, you need to show not just the output of the command with the error, but all the commands you issued in the tutorial and their outputs prior to that point. Copying the contents of the terminal window (after sanitizing) should be sufficient.

Comment: If you're using `require` for the www module, and its not an npm module, you need to specify the correct path, so `require('./bin/www')` or so.

Comment: Where do I place "require('./bin/www')"? Thanks again for the help. I can take a video of what I am doing if that will help you understand my problem.

Comment: If anyone can help with this it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a empty repo from BitBucket it creates a workspace folder. Move the contents of that folder to the root of your cloud9 project.

OR

start from scratch and make sure to run "express . --hbs" in the correct folder

Run

```
**@**:~/workspace (master) $ express . --hbs
```

Not

```
 **@**:~/workspace/workspace (master) $ express . --hbs
```